# Evaluation time of bash subcommands

Tags: bash

I needed to write a bash script to accomplish some task, and found that this code resulted in an infinite loop:

```
echo "Waiting for job to complete"
until [ "$(curl "$url" -u $CREDENTIALS 2>/dev/null)" == "Idle" ]; do
    echo -n "."
    sleep 30
done
```

Even after the result of my `curl` command was equal to `"Idle"`, the loop kept on going, apparently using the old result of the `curl` command in every comparison.

Extracting the `curl` command to a temporary variable fixed this problem.

When does bash expand the `$`'s?  What other "gotcha's" should I watch out for?

**EDIT**:

In light of how platform specific my example is, I reproduced the example in a cross-platform way:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This will result in an infinite loop, and I don't know why

i=0
mocked() {
    i=$(($i+1))
    if [ $i -lt 5 ]; then
        echo "Non-Idle"
    else
        echo "Idle"
    fi
}

until [ "$(mocked)" == "Idle" ]; do
    echo -n "."
done
```

Changing the conditional in `mocked` to `if false` will cause the `until` loop to never run, so I'm sure there's some sort of caching issue.

**EDIT 2**:

All experimentation indicates that this was some freak accident that never happens under normal circumstances, not a limitation of bash.  Regardless, I'm keeping my `curl` command in a temporary variable.  (The second reproduction of the issue was a coincidence, scope in bash is messed up.)

Comment: Make the first statement of your script `set -x` .. this will show you exactly what and when variables are being expanded.

Comment: Most likely, the case where you seem to think the result of your `curl` command is `"Idle"`, it in fact actually has some whitespace either before or after, which will not pass your comparison operation...

Comment: @Jens Modified my comment a bit - any whitespace before, and non-newline whitespace after would be a possible scenario. You are correct that trailing (but not leading) newlines would be removed.

Comment: When it worked was the comparison `until [ $curlvar == "Indle" ]; do` by any chance?

Comment: @EtanReisner when it worked, it was `until [ "$_status" == "Idle" ]; do` (single quotes around my var)

Comment: Okay, the example with the `$(mocked)` loops forever because `i` does **not** get incremented because `$(mocked)` starts a subshell which can't modify variables in the parent. Each time mocked() is called, it sees i=0, sets i=1 and is Non-Idle.

Comment: I think if you change `"$(curl "$url" -u $CREDENTIALS 2>/dev/null)"` to `$(curl "$url" -u $CREDENTIALS 2>/dev/null)` then it should work. Note that it's exactly the same as before except without the surrounding quotes.

Comment: Run your second repro under `bash -x`; watch how `i` is never incremented beyond 1.  Whether that explains the result of the other is open to debate.

Comment: @seane Dropping those quotes is *not* safe or the appropriate solution.

Comment: Retest with `mocked` using `i=$( d=$(date +%S) ; echo ${d: -1} )`.  This returns the last digit of the current second from your clock and is one way of getting a changing value to test your loop with.

Comment: I'd love to investigate the root cause of this further, but the original script takes 15 minutes to run, and I need to go back to doing real work.  All reasonable mockings of the task work perfectly, so I assume it's some sort of nuance with `curl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command substitution is performed each time the condition is evaluated (i.e. for each loop iteration).

It looks like there's something else going on, which we can't be sure since you don't tell us what `$url` contains. Simply put, the output of that `curl` command is *never* `Idle`. We could say more if you gave us the result of

```
 printf '<%s>' $(curl "$url" -u $CREDENTIALS)
```

For example, this little snippet works in bash quite as intended. It stops when the seconds part of the current time hits 42:

```
 set -x ; until [ $(date +%S) = 42 ]; do echo -n .; sleep 0.5; done
```

PS: testing for string equality should be done with the `=` operator. The `==` is a non-portable bashism invented for the ignorant. In other shells it may not be recognized. Please unlearn it as soon as you can. Long live POSIX :-)

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited my question with a better reproduction of the issue.